# Angular JS Folder Upload

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, directory

I know that Chrome has api for folder upload. But I have found that the feature is marked as deprecated and will be removed soon. Does someone know other way to do folder upload?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in any language to upload folder without some crazy lib which will basicly still upload it one by one :)

Comment: Do you know any crazy lib?)

Comment: I afraid I dont

Answer (score 0):

Uploading folder is not possible. You may upload single file, multiple files or zip files.

For this you may use ng-file-upload